# FetchXML with outer joins and nested inner joins: Is it possible to do an outer join on a nested inner join?

Tags: inner-join, outer-join, fetchxml

I am attempting to do some nested joins using FetchXML. I want to do an inner join on two linked child entities, and then do an outer join on that result to retrieve all rows from the parent along with the data from the two linked child entities if it exists. I only want data from childEntity1 if there are records in childEntity2, but I always want all rows from the parent.

In T-SQL it would be something like

```
SELECT [fields] FROM ParentEntity OUTER JOIN 
    (childEntity1 INNER JOIN childEntity2 ON childEntity1.id = 
    childEntity2.childEntity1id) 
ON ParentEntity.id = childEntity1.parentEntityId.
```

In FetchXML, when I use link-type=outer for everything, I get all rows from the parent entity as expected, but when I change the link-type on the child entities to inner, my result set does not include rows where nothing is returned from the join of the two child entities.

Is it possible to nest an inner join like in the SQL statement above in FetchXML?

Here's a simplified version of my FetchXML. When the link-type on childEntity1/childEntity2 is "outer", I get all my rows from the parentEntity, but when it's "inner", the parentEntity's rows are filtered by the results of the child entities' join.

```
<fetch version='1.0' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
    <entity name='parentEntity'>
        <link-entity link-type='outer' name='childEntity1' from='parentEntityId' to='parentEntityId'>
            <link-entity link-type='inner' name='childEntity2' from='childEntity1Id' to='childEntity1Id'>
            </link-entity>
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: All right folks, I'm embarrassed to admit but I think the nested join is actually working as expected. I had some data rows that were masquerading as things they weren't and it was messing up my query (or so I thought). At any rate, SQL Profiler showed me exactly what gets sent to the DB and it was what I wanted all along.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I remember having tested this and it did not give me the results I expected... The problem arises when you try to add a filter condition to retrieve only the 'left' results

Answer (score 1):

See my comment above. SQL Profiler came to my rescue and showed me exactly what was getting sent to the database, and the joins were being nested the way I wanted.